# The number $e^{e^{-1}}$ and two problems with this number in the solution.

Tags: real-analysis

You can show that the graph of $y=b^x$ and $y=x$ are tangent to each other when $b=e^{e^{-1}}$. You can also show that the power tower $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$ (defined as $a_1=x$ and $a_n=x^{a_{n-1}}$ for $n>1$ and $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$) converges when $x\in\left[e^{-e},e^{e^{-1}}\right]$. In both cases, the number $e^{e^{-1}}$ appears. Is this just a numerical coincidence or is there some connection between the two problems?

Comment: Well, considering that if the limit of the sequence defined exists (call it $L$) then $L = a_1^{L}$ looks like the same problem...

Comment: If you see similarities in math , you can always make a connection sometimes limited. Here the converge of your towoer power is related to a fixed point. But $e^e{^-1}$ can also appear when trying to have an integral expression of $ \sum_{p \in \mathbb{N}} p^{-p}$. So connection can be very beautiful and meaningful, or simply similarities without trying to force any closed link.